# Kafka consumer not consuming messages after restart

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Below is the configuration and code for kafka consumer. It works fine on initialization but does not process any further records when consumer restarts after failure. ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT is false, SESSION_TIMEOUT is 30 sec and POLL_TIMEOUT is 0 sec

```
val props = new Properties
  props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, config.getString(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS).get)
  props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZATION, config.getString(KEY_DESERIALIZATION).get)
  props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZATION, config.getString(VALUE_DESERIALIZATION).get)
  props.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT, config.getString(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT).get)
  props.put(GROUP_ID, "ng-evisit")
  props.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT, config.getNumber(SESSION_TIMEOUT).get)

  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props: Properties)
  val partitionInfo: List[PartitionInfo] =
    consumer.partitionsFor(config.getString(TOPIC).get).asScala.toList
  val partitions: util.Collection[TopicPartition] = partitionInfo
    .map(x => new TopicPartition(config.getString(TOPIC).get, x.partition()))
    .asJavaCollection

  consumer.assign(partitions)

while (true){
    try {
          val records = consumer.poll(config.getLong(POLL_TIMEOUT).get)
          for (record <- records.asScala) {
            val value = record.value
            logger.info(
              "Received messages from kafka: " + record.value)
            f(value)
            doCommitSync()
          }

        } catch {
          case e: WakeupException =>
            logger.error("Kafka Consumer Error: " + e.getMessage)
          case e: Throwable =>
            logger.error("Kafka Consumer Error: " + e.getMessage)
            throw e
        }
}
```

Where f is function to perform on value received

```
def doCommitSync(): Unit = {
        try {
          consumer.commitSync()
        } catch {
          case e: WakeupException =>
            doCommitSync()
            throw e
          case e: CommitFailedException =>
            logger.error(e.getMessage)
        }
      }
      }
```

Please suggest, using first time kafka consumer. Have been trying to fix this problem for a long time now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you describe your consumer groups, what is the offset and lag in your topic for it?

Comment: can you see the lag for your topic consumer group?

Comment: Where are you handling this `throw e` in `case e: Throwable` in your while loop ? Where is the restart logic ? The way I see it, you have a potentially infinite throwing of `WakeupException` in your `case e: WakeupException` block

Comment: First of all, you should replace `case e: WakeupException =>
            doCommitSync()` by `case e: WakeupException =>
            consumer.commitSync()` to avoid potentially infinite throw loop.

Comment: consumer logic is in akka actor which is monitored by a parent actor which restarts  comsumer actor when there is an error. Restart is working fine and it goes to consumer.poll but but never gets ahead messages which comes in between restart

Comment: Also i am closing consumer when actor restarts..so clean restart

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 Yes lag is there since messages came in between restart

Comment: To be clear, everything works fine in normal situation. I am testing this logic for any errors, so i restart my consumer actor explicitly and things get worse when restart is done. Before restart, commitSync also runs so it is committing last fetched offset also